# What is the best way to do a fetch request in CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do a fetch request against CoreData. Previously I have first checked if an error existed, and if it did not I have checked the array of the returned entity. Is there a quicker way to do this. Is something like this an accepted way to do the request?

```
let personsRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")

var fetchError : NSError?

//Is it okay to do the fetch request like this? What is more efficient?
if let personResult = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(personRequest, error: &fetchError) as? [Person] {

    println("Persons found: \(personResult.count)")

}
else {

    println("Request returned no persons.")

    if let error = fetchError {

        println("Reason: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
}
```

Kind Regards,
Fisher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the return value of `executeFetchRequest()` first is correct.
The return value is `nil` if the fetch failed, in that case the error
variable *will be set*, so there is no need to check `if let error = fetchError`.

Note that the request does not fail if no (matching) object exist.
In that case an empty array is returned.

```
let personRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
var fetchError : NSError?
if let personResult = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(personRequest, error: &fetchError) as? [Person] {
    if personResult.count == 0 {
        println("No person found")
    } else {
        println("Persons found: \(personResult.count)")
    }
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(fetchError!.localizedDescription)")
}
```