# Xcode Coredata: Fetch two values from one CoreData entity and insert to another CoreData entity within loop function

Tags: xcode, swiftui, nspredicate

Im very new with CoreData fetching/display and so far able to save into CoreData from a JSON fetch.

The fetched data is an array of Airport info with only three items; airport_code, access_point and image_url.

I need to add two more values to each fetched item - a lat and lon coordinate which is stored in another CoreData entity with a matching airport_code item/attribute.

Can anyone provide some guidance as to how to create a separate function to query this other CoreData during the loop sequence by using the predicate value of the airport_code? I have attached the code I have so far:

```
    func saveData(context: NSManagedObjectContext){


        xArray.forEach { (data) in
            
            let entity = Airports(context: context)
            entity.airport_code = data.airport_code
            entity.access_points = data.access_points
            entity.image_url = data.image_url
            entity.lat = getLat()
            entity.lon = getLon()
        }
        
        do{
            try context.save()
            print("Success Saving to CoreData: \(xArray.count)")
        }
        catch{
            print("Error Saving to CoreData \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    
    func getLat() -> String {
        @FetchRequest(entity: AllAirports.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \AllAirports.airport_code, ascending: true)])
        var results: FetchedResults<AllAirports>
        //this is where Im lost as to how to query this CoreData to fetch the LON value when there is a match to the data.airport_code in the loop above.
        
        return latResults
    }

    func getLon() -> String {
        @FetchRequest(entity: AllAirports.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \AllAirports.airport_code, ascending: true)])
        var results: FetchedResults<AllAirports>
        //this is where Im lost as to how to query this CoreData to fetch the LON value when there is a match to the data.airport_code in the loop above.
        
        return lonResults
    }



func fetchData(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
// this function performs a JSON parse and returns the xArray above
….
```

Comment: You are trying to do some fetch requests using `@FetchRequest` which is some SwiftUI specific functionality... Those property wrappers cannot be used in a function in a usable way. You will have to write a fetch request.  I suppose your `getLat()` and `getLon()` methods do not give any sensible data.

Comment: Perhaps checkout a simple Core Data and SwiftUI How To like [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-filter-core-data-fetch-requests-using-a-predicate)

Comment: That's exactly the code I replicated in those two functions.. just not sure how to write the predicate line and reference the "airport_code" from the array during the loop and return the values of lat and lon.  How can I create a public function or struct of this FetchRequest that can be reference from the loop? Will keep trying.  Thanks for the reply

Comment: Based on the little code you have provided. You are using SwiftUI wrappers incorrectly. They should not be inside functions or in a class if this code is in a class. they only work reliably in a SwiftUI View. You have to use the “old” NSFetchRequest https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to take a look at the response here [What is the best way to do a fetch request in CoreData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602139/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-fetch-request-in-coredata) to get an idea how a programmatic fetch request may look like.

As I understand your problem now, you want to write two methods `getLat()` and `getLon()` which are going to fetch the coordinates for an airport.

I would recommend to write a single function as shown below which looks up your airport in `AllAirports` using the given code and returns the tuple with the coordinates found.

```swift
func getCoord(airport_code: String) -> (lon: Double, lat: Double)? {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<AllAirports> = AllAirports.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "airport_code == %@", airport_code)

    if let result = try? viewContext.fetch(request) {
        print("Found \(result.count) airports matching \(airport_code)")

        // Just return the first matched airport
        if let first = result.first {
            return (first.longitude, first.latitude)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

A better solution would be to add an extension to you `AllAirports` which returns an entry for a given (hopefully unique!) `airport_code`:

```swift
extension AllAirports {
    static func airport(byCode airportCode: String, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> AllAirports? {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<AllAirports> = fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "airport_code == %@", airportCode)

        if let result = try? context.fetch(request) {
            return result.first
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This could then be used in your code as follows:

```swift
    func saveData(context: NSManagedObjectContext){
        xArray.forEach { (data) in
            
            let entity = Airports(context: context)
            entity.airport_code = data.airport_code
            entity.access_points = data.access_points
            entity.image_url = data.image_url
            if let airport = AllAirports.airport(byCode: data.airport_code, in: context) {
                entity.lat = airport.latitude
                entity.lon = airport.longitude
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try.  I kind of placed this issue on the "back burner" and working on other items on the app, but will give your solution a try and see what results I get.  Will reply soon.

Comment: Thanks @pd95!  That extension worked great for me.  Really appreciate the reply!

Comment: @CrewFly: If it solved your issue, then it would be nice to accept the answer as "the answer".

Comment: Sorry, Im a little new with SO and just starting to learn the QA protocols.  Thanks for the answer. It's The Answer I was looking for.